# iOS Firebase - Problem to get the photo's url (Unresolved identifier)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Im trying to get the url of the photo which the user selects and then send it to Firebase. Im getting this error in the last line: 
**Use of unresolved identifier 'profileImageUrl'; did you mean 'profileImage'?**

```
@IBAction func signUpBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        }


        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://justforpractice.appspot.com").child("profile_image").child(userID)
        if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = self.selectedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1){
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }


                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    guard let profileImageUrl = url else {
                        // An error occurred!
                        return
                    }
                }

                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                let usersReference = ref.child("users")
                let newUserReference = usersReference.child(userID)
                newUserReference.setValue(["username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])

            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code inside the `storageRef.downloadUrl` closure so you have access to the unwrapped `url`:

```
storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let profileImageUrl = url else {
        // An error occurred!
        return
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersReference = ref.child("users")
    let newUserReference = usersReference.child(userID)
    newUserReference.setValue(["username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @vasil-garov , its working. Now the url is being saved in the Storage but the data is not in the Database.

Comment: If I leave the code like this: https://codeshare.io/5QzmvL I can send the data to the Database but not to the Storage.

Comment: Well, this is normal - you commented out the storage code.

Comment: Hi Vasil, I commented it just to show you that before I added the code to send the url to the Storage, the data related to the Database used to be sent. Now that I added the code related to the Storage, the data related to the Database is not being send anymore. I don't understand why.

Comment: This is the code https://pastebin.com/Jep41WjU Thank you for your help!

Comment: The Storage code you are referring to is still commented out. Show me the storage code you are saying it's not working please.

Comment: So it should be somewhere in the unwrapping of the image / imageData or in the putData code. Make sure you handle these parts properly. Put some error logs and see what happens.